# How do I filter multiple columns in datagridview exported from excel in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview which i import an excel file.my excel columns are name,id,sex,grade,seat no .what i want is filter all the columns (multi column filter) in the datagridview except name and id via a textbox. i.e. when i type a single word in the text box i want it to filter the columns of sex,grade and seat no at the same time.
**here is the excel importing code to the datagridview....**

```
Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
        Dim filePath As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Dim extension As String =
        Path.GetExtension(filePath)
        Dim header As String = If(rbHeaderYes.Checked, "YES", "NO")
        Dim conStr As String, sheetName As String
        conStr = String.Empty
        Select Case extension
            Case ".xls"
                'Excel 97-03
                conStr = String.Format(Excel03ConString, filePath, header)
                Exit Select
            Case ".xlsx"
                'Excel 07
                conStr = String.Format(Excel07ConString, filePath, header)
                Exit Select
        End Select
        'Get the name of the First Sheet.
        Using con As New OleDbConnection(conStr)
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
                cmd.Connection = con
                con.Open()
                Dim dtExcelSchema As DataTable = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
                sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString()
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
        'Read Data from the First Sheet.
        Using con As New OleDbConnection(conStr)
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
                Using oda As New OleDbDataAdapter()
                    Dim dt As New DataTable()
                    cmd.CommandText = (Convert.ToString("SELECT * From [") & sheetName) + "]"
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    con.Open()
                    oda.SelectCommand = cmd
                    oda.Fill(dt)
                    con.Close()
                    'Populate DataGridView.
                    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: What have you done to implement the search functionality?

Comment: You can use the datatable.Select(' insert your condition ') for filtering multiple rows

Answer (score 1):

You should bind your DataTable to a BindingSource, which you would add in the designer, and then bind that to the grid.  You can then filter the data by setting the Filter property of the BindingSource.  It's basically a SQL WHERE clause so, just like in SQL, you can use AND and OR operators to combine multiple criteria, e.g.

```
myBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("Column1 LIKE '%{0}%' OR Column2 LIKE '%{0}%'", myTextBox.Text)
```

Just note that you can only use LIKE for text columns, not numbers or dates or anything else.

Comment: how can i do it with out using a binding source?

Comment: I have edited the code and added a missing reference to the `Filter` property.

Comment: What exactly do you have against using a `BindingSource`? There's no good reason not to. If you're determined to not use one for no good reason then you can set the `DefaultView.RowFilter` property of the `DataTable` instead of the `Filter` property of the `BindiongSource`.